# can't get Lenovo a60+ to appear as an available android device in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Are there any alternative ways to get it to work?

Even the adb command of android sdk doesn't detect my phone. Then some said I need to install the phone drivers first, I thought the phone automatically does it when plugged in while usb debugging is enabled, but it appears that it doesn't.

[image]

I searched for the driver, but was unlucky, it was not included in the memstick that came with the phone. Even the lenovo website doesn't provide it.